How do I call a mudblazor modal dialog in Maui/Blazor hybrid?
I have a maui xaml page. When I click a button I want to show a dialog that exists in my razor class library.
This is a mudblazor modal dialog so I need this to show as an actual modal dialog in my maui app. I have declared  in my mainlayout page in my maui app
So How can I show the mud dialog in maui?
<buttons:SfButton x:Name="button" 
                Text="Button" 
               Clicked="OpenBlazorWebViewAsync" />

Here is how I am calling or at least trying to call the dialog from maui xaml
private async Task OpenBlazorWebViewAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var options = new MudBlazor.DialogOptions() { FullWidth = true,  MaxWidth = MaxWidth.ExtraLarge, DisableBackdropClick = true, Position = DialogPosition.Center, CloseOnEscapeKey = false };

            var dialog = await _dialogService.ShowAsync<SendMessageDialog>("Send Single Message", options);
            var result = await dialog.Result;
            if (result != null)
            {
                int secondsToVibrate = Random.Shared.Next(1, 7);
                TimeSpan vibrationLength = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsToVibrate);

                Vibration.Default.Vibrate(vibrationLength);
                HapticFeedback.Perform(HapticFeedbackType.LongPress);

                await Task.Delay(1000);
                var duration = ToastDuration.Long;
                double fontSize = 14;
                var toast = Toast.Make("Message Sent Successfully", duration, fontSize);
                await toast.Show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            var duration = ToastDuration.Long;
            double fontSize = 14;
            var toast = Toast.Make($@"Error: {ex.Message}", duration, fontSize);
            await toast.Show();
        }
    }

Here is the razor page dialog
    @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Blazored.FluentValidation
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Calendars
@inject IUsersService userService
@inject IDapperContrib _dapperContrib
@inject SweetAlertService Swal;

<MudDialog>
    <DialogContent>
        <EditForm Model="@model">
            <MudSelect class="my-4" @bind-Value="model.FirebaseDeviceId" Label="Users">
                @foreach (var user in users)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.FirebaseDeviceId))
                    {
                        <MudSelectItem Value="@user.FirebaseDeviceId">@($"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}")</MudSelectItem>
                    }
                }
            </MudSelect>
            <MudSelect class="my-4" @bind-Value="model.EventName" Label="Event Name">
                <MudSelectItem Value="@("Calendar")">Calendar</MudSelectItem>
                <MudSelectItem Value="@("Word")">Word</MudSelectItem>
                <MudSelectItem Value="@("Roster")">Roster</MudSelectItem>
            </MudSelect>
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="model.Title" Label="Title" />
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="model.Message" Label="Message" />
        </EditForm>
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
        <MudButton OnClick="Cancel">Cancel</MudButton>
        <MudButton Color="MudBlazor.Color.Primary" Disabled="@(!IsFormValid())" OnClick="Submit">Send Message</MudButton>
    </DialogActions>
</MudDialog>
@code {
    public List<User> users { get; set; } = new List<User>();
    public NotificationModel model { get; set; } = new NotificationModel();

    [CascadingParameter] MudDialogInstance MudDialog { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        users = (List<User>)await _dapperContrib.GetAll<User>();
    }

    private void Cancel()
    {
        MudDialog.Cancel();
    }

    private async void  Submit()
    {
         await userService.SendSpecificUserTestMessage(model);
        await Swal.FireAsync(new SweetAlertOptions
            {
                Title = "Success!",
                TitleText = @$"Message Sent Successfully to user {model.FirebaseDeviceId}",
                Timer = 3000,
                ShowConfirmButton = false,
                Icon = "success",
                HeightAuto = false
            });
        MudDialog.Close();
    }

    private bool IsFormValid()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.FirebaseDeviceId) &&
               !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.EventName) &&
               !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Title) &&
               !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Message);
    }

    private void OnValueChanged()
    {
       
    }
   } 


Instead of if (result != null) try if (!result.Canceled). Also make sure in your mainlayout.razor you have <MudDialogPovider />  with the desired options
